# Mongodb find if field exists using a wherein

Tags: php, mongodb

Essentially is it possible to find documents based on there sub document using $in. For example say I had:

```
array(
'item.1',
'item.2',
'item.3
)
```

would return document that have:

```
{
    item {
        1: {

        }
    }
}
{
    item {
        2: {

        }
    }
}
{
    item {
        3: {

        }
    }
}
```

I know if I had one I could use `db.inventory.find( { qty: { $exists: true, $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )` but how would I do that with a $in?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Mention clearly what you are expecting and the issue you have

Comment: I'm not sure where "qty" came into this discussion...

Comment: Thats from the mongodb documents for $exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query of this form:

```
db.collection.find ( { $or : [
          {"item.1":{$exists:true}},
          {"item.2":{$exists:true}},
          {"item.3":{$exists:true}}
] } );
```

This will return any document which has one or more of "item.X" in this case 1, 2 or 3 set.